# How to use the functions CELL and INDEX together in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use cell and index together to get an address of a certain value in excel vba.

I write the following but it doesn't work as it doesn't know how to read the cell function.

```
PlaceF = Application.WorksheetFunction.CELL("address", Application.WorksheetFunction.Index([G9:L44], [I3], [I4]))
```

Is there any alternative to this or a way to get this function to work?

Comment: Can you clarify the exact data it is you are trying to access with the commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the address of a certain value in a range, use the Find function. In this case, since you seem to know the location of the value, you can return the address by calling `Range(location).Address` where `location` is the "ColumnRow" call of the location

Comment: The data is coming from a match function and so I don't know where the data is coming from. It changes all the time. So I need the function to be dynamic?